# Regular Expression (Regex) Validator to allow only positive whole value with or without commas

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, validation

I've been working on a project with lots of previous developer validation issues and am trying to clean up some issues and add validation in spots.

I generally use this simple regex that allows only positive whole values and can accept commas if they are entered:

```
"^([0-9]*,?)*$"
```

But in this case my program won't run if `0` is the value entered, so I need `1` to be the minimum value allowed. All else is the same. No decimals or any of that stuff.

I'm assuming I just need to add "not 0" to my regex, but not sure how to do that.

Allowed:

```
3,200
650
5
134560
100,000
```

Not Allowed:

```
0
3.2
-3.2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
^[1-9]([0-9]*,?)*$
```

The first character cannot be a `0` and since it isn't optional either...